# HTML Media Capture and video

Tags: javascript, html, video, web-applications, smartphone

I saw this link http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/camera/ and I can upload video on my smartphone. But I need to show the video just after the user record.

It's exactly like the example 6 but with video, not image.

The project it's allow the user to record one or more video and use a framework like popcorn.js with own video, not youtube or other.

And the all without internet, in local webapp... 
I'm a little lost ^^

Thank you !

Comment: Check out this JSfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/cCCZ2/

Comment: Great ! Ty. Where are your sources? I can be interested by the tutorial or other :)

Comment: And it's does'nt work in iOs device (iPhone) but ok on android.